# How to select all SessionID in cmd (Without Administrator's SessionID)

Tags: batch-file, session, cmd, rdp, sessionid

I can select all Active and Disconnected rdp session with the following command:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4" %a in ('"query session | findstr "Attivo Disc""') do echo %a %b
```

**Cicle OUTPUT**

```
0 Disc
1 Disc
Administrator 17
User4 19
20 Disc
User10 21
22 Disc
24 Disc
```

**Query Process OUTPUT**

```
 NOMESESSIONE      NOMEUTENTE               ID  STATO   TIPO        DISPOSITIVO
 services                                    0  Disc                        
                   User1                     1  Disc                        
>rdp-tcp#55        Administrator            17  Attivo                      
 rdp-tcp#51        User4                    19  Attivo                      
                   User5                    20  Disc                        
 rdp-tcp#53        User10                   21  Attivo                      
                   User3                    22  Disc                        
                   User7                    24  Disc                        
 console                                    25  Conn                        
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Rimani in ascolto
```

How can I extract both active and disconnected **SessionID** excluding the administrator SessionID?

Comment: Switch to using the `FINDSTR` command. `query session | findstr "Active Disconnected"`.  You will need to pipe to another find command to remove the admin session.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2-4" %a in ('"query session | findstr "Active Disconnetcted""') do echo %b` doesn't return a correct output: it returns me "echo disconnected" (not SessionID) when it refers to disconnected sessions

Comment: How about [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51736284/edit), to include the complete output from, `Query Session>output.log`. When you paste it into your question body, select its entire content and press on the `{}` button to ensure that it's format remains in tact.

Comment: Well you never said the `TOKENS` would change by adding `Disc` to the `FINDSTR` command.  Obviously you will need to have two `FOR /F` commands.  One for Active and one for Disconnected as the output has a different amount of tokens for each.

Comment: @Squalo, he asked you for the output of `Query Session`.  Not the output from the `FOR /F` command.

Comment: Thanks @Squashman, you beat me to it. Please repeat the process replacing what you've added with what I asked for.

Comment: I wrote the correct output. Thanks

Comment: I am thinking the Session number is always in a fixed position but I could be wrong.  Regardless of that you could look at the header and figure out the starting position of each column and then use sub-strings to extract the correct positions of the data.  I actually do this for some weird data I get from a client of ours.

Comment: Look again! If i use %a and %b i can retrieve all SessionID but now i need to isolate Administrator SessionID and all others SessionID!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this all with one line of code at the cmd prompt.  A batch file is more suited for this type of manipulation.

Comment: Can you post an example? Thanks!

Comment: The Administrator is showing as the current session, so it follows that you're running this as Administrator. If that's always the case, likely because of permissions, then there may be a simple method of ignoring an line which begins with the current session designator, **`>`**.

Comment: @Compo yes! I need to activate that script with administrator privilege

Comment: Based on my last comment your `For` loop can easily ignore the `Administrator` and `Skip` the first line by using, `For /F "EOL=> Skip=1 Tokens=2,4" %A In (…`, however, as previously noted it is clear that the output table does not contain the same number of `Tokens` on each line and will not output what you need!

Comment: @Compo but the administrator isn‘t always the first!

Comment: @Squalo, no the header you don't want is skipped using `Skip=1` the Administrator entry is ignored because when run as Administrator its end of line character is always a **`>`**, i.e. `EOL=>`!